# Inno Setup: wpselectDir not displaying make new folder

Tags: inno-setup

when browse button is clicked on the wpselectdir wizard, the pop-up window is not displaying "make new folder". In the help, they say if the `DefaultDirName` is set to no, it causes a Make New Folder button to appear on the dialog. I tried to set as no in the [setup] section, which didnt work. Please help.

Note: I created a wizard page from `CreateInputDirPage`, where in i have the option to make it display, which is working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Browse For Folder` dialog's `Make New Folder` button visibility has a special rule to be there. You must have [`AppendDefaultDirName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appenddefaultdirname) directive explicitly set to `no` since by default is `yes`. As a consequence, it will disable automatic adding a path to the selected folder but there's no other way to get `Make New Folder` button visible (checked in InnoSetup source):

```
[Setup]
AppendDefaultDirName=no
```

Comment: The reason that this is the case is that with `AppendDefaultDirName=yes` then it will usually always result in creating a new folder anyway, so there's no need to create a new one as the destination.  (You are actually selecting the parent folder, not the real target folder.)